# Finding the n most distant points on a cube

Tags: optimization, analytic-geometry

I am trying to pick the $n$ most distant colors from each other to make the most varied palette possible.  Since the most commonly used color space (RGB) is a cube, this means I need to know the $n$ most distant points on that cube.

By most distant points, I mean that the two closest points have as high a distance between them as possible.

For $n = 2 \lor 3 \lor 4 \lor 8 \lor 9$, the answers are simple, but for other $n$ there seems to be no obvious way to calculate them apart from brute force computation.

Comment: This is [an open problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCode.html) when the cube is replaced by a sphere, which would seem to make it simpler.  I suggest you try a sort of dynamic model, where you initially position the points at random and then have them repel each other as if they were point charges acting under an electrostatic force.  This approach may produce results good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Also I wonder if the answers for $n=3$ and $n=9$ are as simple as you think.  (The answer to the corresponding problem of placing 8 points on a sphere is not necessarily the one you would expect either.)

Comment: @MJD The answer for $n = 3$ is $$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
  & \text{x} & \text{y} & \text{z} \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
$$
The answer for $n = 9$ is$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
  & \text{x} & \text{y} & \text{z} \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
6 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
7 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
8 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
9 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5
\end{array}
$$